# Spring MVC "Cannot resolve MVC view"

Tags: java, spring, mvc, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Все работало нормально, у меня шел учебный процесс, мог открывать разные проекты, но в какой-то момент перестало находить view.

Я открываю готовый код курса, который 100% работает ( открывал его ранее ), но оно мне пишет `Сannot resolve MVC view 'hello_world'`.

**Вот контроллер:**

```
package ru.alishev.springcourse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

    @Controller
    public class HelloController {
    
        @GetMapping("/hello-world")
        public String sayHello() {
            return "hello_world";
        }
    }
```

**Вот контекст:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.alishev.springcourse"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
        <property name="enableSpringELCompiler" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="viewNames" value="*"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Вот Web XML:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
             id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    
        <display-name>spring-mvc-app1</display-name>
    
        <absolute-ordering/>
    
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContextMVC.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
    
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    
    </web-app>
```

Вот структура в скрине:

[image: Структура]

P.S. Может это с томкатом связано?

Answer (score 0):

> Нужна 9 версия Tomcat. Тогда все будет работать.

Я перепробовал все варианты. Помог именно этот. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующую конфигурацию для вью резолвера.

```
<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/>
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="viewNames" value="*.html"/>
</bean>
```